# Dashed line style in ttk Treeview

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I am creating simple Tkinter app with ttk Treeview widget. I know tkinter is more limited with style, but wondering that there is any way to make its syle "Dashed line" like this?:

[image]

Comment: As near as I can tell, Treeview does not use lines, solid or dashed, at all and there is no way to add them.  If you want such, you need to create a tk widget based on a tk Canvas.  You could start by copying existing code that does this, such as lib/idlelib/TreeWidget.py (/tree.py in 3.6).

Comment: Got it, but what about Python IDLE's path browser? Was it not created using tkinter?

Comment: Yes.  The browsers uses tree.py, not (as yet), a ttk Treeview, which uses a tk canvas with carefully placed canvas items (images, text, and lines).